# How do I create a SQL Server OleDbConnection using a data source that is the name of an excel spreadsheet file?

Tags: sql-server

Our office would like to replace Microsoft Jet OLEDB 4.0 with a SQL Server OleDbConnection in order to run an import of Excel spreadsheet records into a sql database table. We're trying to avoid using Microsoft Jet OLEDB 12.0 for 64 bit machines because it will not install in the presence of 32 bit office products like Office Enterprise 2007 or MS Office 2003. The original MS Jet 4.0 connection string works for 32 bit apps, but our client will not let us to turn on 32 bit apps in IIS on their 64 bit server. Here is the original MS Jet 4.0 connection string:

```
       Dim xlConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                  "Data Source=C:\ServerFolder\" & fName & ";" & _
                  "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""
```

When I replace that with the following, I have problems:

```
       Dim xlConnStr As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
                  "Data Source=C:\ServerFolder\" & fName & ";" & _
                  "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ACE drivers instead of Jet. There are various versions; download the one that seems best for you although I don't think that there's much difference. [This](http://www.bing.com/search?q=ace%20drivers%20for%20excel&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IESR02) search will find a few, plus some articles.

For the connection string, the ever-helpful connectionstrings.com has [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/).

ACE is the 64-bit replacement for JET.

Comment: This is a version of the database engine for later versions of office, and it does at least install. The issue I'm running into is that I cannot install ACE for 64 bit machines without uninstalling the 32 bit Microsoft Excel, etc from Office. I can install the 32 bit version of ACE for Office 2010 (Microsoft.ACE.OLDB.14.0), but that doesn't help because I'm not allowed to turn on 32 bit applications in IIS app pools. We're running this from background visual basic on an ASP web application.

Comment: Honestly, this solution you've provided is clearly the right thing to do. Microsoft makes it clear that this engine is used for that purpose; and it may be that Jet 12 will do it also. I think I need to try these out on a machine that doesn't have the older versions of office on it. Thanks for the help. It's appreciated.